# Javascript constructor copies array as empty when it should contain items

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
function BayesNet(vars) {
 this.variables = {};
 this.numVars = Object.keys(this.variables).length;
    for (v in vars) {
      this.variables[v] = new BayesNode(vars[v]);
      this.variables[v].CPTorder = this.generateDomainRows(this.variables[v].parents);
      this.variables[v].fullCPT = {}
      for (var i = 0; i < this.variables[v].CPTorder.length; i++) {
         this.variables[v].fullCPT[this.variables[v].CPTorder[i]] = this.variables[v].CPT[i];
      }
       this.variables[v].blocks = false;
  } 
}


function BayesNode(obj) {
    this.parents = obj.parents;
    this.children = obj.children;
    if (typeof obj.domain == 'undefined')
        this.domain = ['T','F'];
    else
        this.domain = obj.domain;
    this.observation = obj.observation;
    this.CPT = obj.CPT;

    this.sampleDistribution = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.CPT.length; i++) {
        var s = [];
        if(this.CPT[i].length == this.domain.length - 1)
            this.CPT[i].push(1 - sumArray(this.CPT[i]));
        s.push(this.CPT[i][0]);
        for (var j = 1; j < this.domain.length - 1; j++) {
           s.push(this.CPT[i][j]+s[j-1]);
        }
        s.push(1.0);
        this.sampleDistribution.push(s);
    }
    //TODO: Check if CPT is valid
}
```

My problem is that BayesNode.parent is copied incorrectly.

BayesNode.parent should be an array containing items, and when I run the debugger through the constructor, this.parents is the correct value . However, once I go back to the BayesNet constructor, parents is an empty array. What could be causing this? All other variables in the object behave as expected.

Comment: remember, javascript is async. that is the root cause of your problem

Comment: You don't copy `parents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript executes function calls asynchronously. This is the root cause of your issue. You should use callbacks to execute code that is dependent on results of function calls.

Let me explain this using your code:

```
this.variables[v] = new BayesNode(vars[v]);
this.variables[v].CPTorder = this.generateDomainRows(this.variables[v].parents);
```

When you call the constructor, JS does NOT wait for the function to finish executing before moving onto the next line of code. When JS comes across "this.variables[v].parents", it is empty, because, the function call in the previous line is still executing asynchronously.

Javascript code design requires a different approach as compared to most other languages.

Comment: Is there a way to force javascript to wait for the function to finish before continuing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in your code, its strange why its becoming empty. but to solve the problem there is a way. change the code as follow.

after this line

```
   this.variables[v] = new BayesNode(vars[v]);
```

Add the follow

```
   this.variables[v].parents = vars[v].parents;
```

I see you are not modifying the parents in the constructor, it will work for time being before you find out whats happening. you might have done this already :)